# Policy to allow user/password login with non-interactive flow

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, idp, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently trying to connect from a checking app (uses custom authentication) to my reporting app (uses AD B2C) . I have the user/password for the reporting user in AD B2C (reporting application user is created from external API call that creates reporting user in AD B2C).  I want to connect from the checking app using the reporting user/password and be redirected to the reporting pages without AD B2C challenge.

I can get the access_token from AD B2C reporting app using

```
POST https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com
/<APP_policy>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<App_ID>
redirect_uri: <<reporting app>>
grant_type:password
username: <user>
password:<pswd>
scope:openid https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/appID/Custom.Scope
response_type:token id_token
```

I need to be able to use the access_token in the downstream links.
Is this scenario possible ? How should my policy be configured for this to work?

[image: App flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really poor security design, and opens yourself up to a lot of exploits - we could not recommend something like this.

A better approach would be to us `id_token_hint` to bootstrap the journey:
[sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md). Instead of sending U/P in the clear, you send a signed JWT to App2, which sends it to B2C and B2C processes the JWT and logs the user in automatically. This also allows you to use the native MSAL libraries to manage the tokens.

Comment: I have tried to create a flow based on the comment from the App1  (Checking App) I have created a link  (on the lines of ID Token Builder) - https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_mytenant&client_id=a8e553dxx-xx...4&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&nonce=df8efa8eb3eb499ab45f3b1adf42feed&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&id_token_hint=ey..

Comment: 2. As step2 I have added 2 paths   -  [Route(".well-known/openid-configuration", Name = "OIDCMetadata")] and   [Route(".well-known/keys", Name = "JWKS")] for the metadata endpoints .  Step 3 - I need the Custom policy (clicking on link from step 1 //comment above)  - to redirect to these endpoint and validate the user/password . I am unable to get this working. Would you have a sample in continuation with a policy for ID Token Builder  that I can refer to .